# Browser compatibility issues with PHP website

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a website called `www.kratosguide.com`.

The site works as expected for approximately 90% of users, however, I have been getting a LOT of complaints recently that the page doesn't load completely in certain browsers such as chrome/firefox/opera.

Here is a screenshot that someone sent me of how the page loads: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCH3G.jpg

It appears that only the header and footer is loading and the content from `index.php` is not.

http://www.reddit.com/r/productivity/comments/w1y30/16_habits_you_should_do_everyday/

Here is a link that demonstrates a user stating the issue above -- (4th comment down).

My host is unable to replicate the issue on their end and they say it works fine.  My friend kept refreshing his page cache and he could replicate the error but only intermittently.

Thanks in advance.

*****EDIT: I forgot to mention the site runs on WordPress, also the site works fine for me in every browser, which makes it hard for me to see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is and maybe show some of your internal code? Also can you be more specific regarding the browsers? Chrome/Firefox/Opera is probably more than 50% of your total visitors... this will be very hard to diagnose without better info

Comment: Can't replicate on chrome 20.0.1132.47 m for windows

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128553#128553)

Comment: Im sorry, I should mention the site runs on WordPress. The issue is that for a certain people, the site loads only the header and footer, and not index.php as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/sqNX4.jpg

It works for the majority of people in Chrome/Firefox/Opera BUT for some people it doesn't.. which is what is driving me crazy because I don't know how to target the problem.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame That link is not visible to meta users without high rep, I'm guessing it was deleted.

Comment: @user1504640 - see my comment about how to target the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check the console. You have some errors

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - 068690ea.84e407.js:24`

Probably caused by this script being called before the jquery library.

It's difficult to tell what is causing the error without being able to replicate it. I'd try to load it in various browsers and see if I can get it to do that. Then take a look at the console for any errors and inspect the DOM to see if the content even loads.

Comment: That sounds like it hasn't loaded JQuery.

Comment: Do you think this is probably a JavaScript issue then? Its difficult for me to replicate the error because the site works for me in every browser I try.

Comment: Could be. You should fix the errors regardless of this issue.

Comment: I reuploaded the entire JS folder to my site and overwrote the old one. Does this error still happen?

Comment: Check the console (`Ctrl Shift J` or Wrench > Tools > JS Console). You always had jQuery, the other script just gets included before it.

Comment: Ohh ok I see what you mean now. Sorry I'm not too great with any topic dealing with JavaScript. How do I make sure that jQuery loads before the other scripts?

Comment: Put the line that includes jquery before the lines that include the other scripts.

Comment: Ok I made sure that this line of code comes before any other scripts: 

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

Its located in the header right after my google analytics code. Error still pops up though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I still see the errors in the log.

Let me be clearer.

For me the web page loads and is visible 100%, but when I look at the console I see what is shown below.  This is an indication you have a problem.  My personal settings allow me to see the page but with different settings or plugins I would not be able to see the page.  You need to fix your XSS error.

**You can reproduce the problem yourself!**

Download chrome (or firefox) and then load the page, look at the console, see the error.

Then fix it.

*Original answer below*

---

First step, fix these errors shown by chrome.  Looks like you have a XSS error.

[image]

Comment: I reuploaded the entire JS folder to my site and overwrote the old one. Does this error still happen?

Answer (score 0):

I saw over 1200 unused CSS element on your page. Try to optimize the amount of data a user has to download to see your website. I had similar issues with my site and I realized how much stuff users had to load to see my website.

I tested it under Firefox, Chrome, IE7+. I didn't get any issues.

You seems to be using WordPress so you might want to check the WordPress community for similar problem.